# Inline Text view of another Text View

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I have a TextView with a paragraph and inside of the paragraph, I want to add another TextView on which I'll implement onClickListner to add a small text from the user. But as the 1st text view reaches the end of the screen, the second layout vanishes.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="when this content reaches the end of the screen, the text view next to it disappears"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="{Tap to enter Recipient's name}"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[This is the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YdIv.png)

Comment: Add the text view in a scroll view

Comment: pls show your code

Comment: I have the same issue and I implemented a library but the library only take the 2nd text view below the 1st when 1st TextView reaches the end if the screen

Comment: @Usane Boult, have you look at this library? might help you out. https://github.com/nakshay/TextHighlighter

Comment: @JayDangar but this library won't allow onClickListner on the specific text? is it?

Comment: @PraveenP i have attached a snapshot

Comment: @UsaneBoult, you can ask the creator of the library or look for alternative as well.

Comment: @UsaneBoult, i have found one, which will definitely solve your problem. Take a look at this one -> https://github.com/klinker24/Android-TextView-LinkBuilder

Comment: @JayDangar thaks for your assistance, I'll implement it and will respond yout, hope that this will work for me.

Comment: @JayDangar it woked!

Comment: @Usane Boult, enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Add orientation in your LinearLayout with `android:orientation="vertical"`.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="when this content reaches the end of the screen, the text view next to it disappears" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="{Tap to enter Recipient's name}" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its complete in the question

Answer (score 0):

[image]try this code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="when this content reaches the end of the screen, the text view next to it disappears"
            android:textSize="24dp"
    />
    <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="{Tap to enter Recipient's name}"
            android:textSize="24dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: wait let me show you the screen shot because its working for me

Comment: @UsaneBoult check it out